# Prove or disprove: f(n-1) is omega(f(n))

Tags: complexity-theory

Prove or disprove: f(n-1) is omega(f(n)).
I actually need a more specific example of this but I thought this claim was interesting.
I want to know if (n-1)log(n-1) is omega(nlogn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show $(n-1)! \neq \Omega(n!)$